# React native lightbox center image

Tags: react-native, lightbox

Hi everyone I'm trying to use lightbox. Here's my source code.

```
  <Lightbox>
        <Image
          source={require('../img/sample.png')}
          style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            resizeMode: 'contain',//also tryed cover
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
        />
      </Lightbox>
```

It opens image like this. How can I fix it

[image]

to

[image]

added new code but same

[image]

Comment: Could you create an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: But this is the all code they in a view  with style  marginVertical={5}
            justifyContent={'flex'}
            alignItems={'flex'}
            flex={3}
            borderRadius={20}

Comment: have you tried styling `Lightbox` with `{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}`

Comment: Box means view it comes from styledcomponents

Comment: Anyone to help with this